# Download file from SQL Server and save to fix folder using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I developed a web application using C#, I upload file to SQL Server. I need to auto-download it to a folder.

Here is my code for that:

```
string sql = "select * from tblFiles where ID = " + ID ;

DataTable dt = dbs.MNTSQLSelect(sql);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["contentType"].ToString();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["fileName"].ToString());
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["filedata"]);
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortantly the download location as a genreal rule is controlled by the "end user" browser settings.

For up-loading, then you ONLY ever get just the file name, and information about the client side computer is "hands off". If you could set/pick/choose a file name, then while you come to my site to view a picture of a cute cat?

Then I could start rummanging around on your hard drive. Steal your emails, or how about files in a folder called "banking". or how aobut looking for a Excel sheet called passwords?

It turns out that while file up-loads don't allow ANY kind of path information, or even exposing path names to your web server?

You can try passing a path name + file name when sending a file to a client computer. But, then again, this might be an adroid phone, iPad, and as such, things like drive letters don't even exist!

So, I have found that I can supply a path name - Edge seems to accept the path name, but at the end of the day, it the end users browser settings that has and will control where a file location is downloaded to
(in most cases - it defaults to the folder called "downloads").

so, you really don't have much choice in this matter - the end user computer + browser settings will ultimately control the location of such downloads, and once again, if any old location could be set, then I might as well download some .exe program into your windows startup folder or whatever - and again that would be a security risk beyond anything that any user would allow or tolerate.

You can't mess around with my computer JUST because I decide to visit your site, and as noted, no end user would use a browser or the internet if this was possible.